# How to call lists from a function in the main program?

Tags: python, list, function, sum, return

I need to use 2 lists from a function that is then called to calculate the sum of these lists. How can I do it using functions and arguments?

```
def lists():
    list1 = [150, 250, 190, 230]
    list2 = [110, 200, 125, 130]

def sumOfLists():
    sum = sum(list1) + sum(list2)
    return sum

sumOfLists()
```

Comment: Why is `lists` a function at all?

Comment: I'm constrained to used them in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lists` should return the lists.
`sumOfLists` should get the 2 lists and return the sum of them.

```
def lists():
    list1 = [150, 250, 190, 230]
    list2 = [110, 200, 125, 130]
    return list1,list2


def sumOfLists(list1,list2):
    return sum(list1) + sum(list2)

print(sumOfLists(*lists()))
```

Comment: I'm trying your method, but I can't get the answer to be printed out. I'm using Python 3.4.1.

Comment: i change the answer to support python 3.4. it was the print function syntax

Answer (score 1):

Just make **`lists()`** function to return the lists and the unpack them in **`sumOfLists()`**:

```
def lists():
    list1 = [150, 250, 190, 230]
    list2 = [110, 200, 125, 130]
    return list1, list2

def sumOfLists():
    list1, list2 = lists()
    return sum(list1) + sum(list2)

print sumOfLists()
```

**Output:**

```
1385
```